Need Help Understanding AMD Hardware Acceleration problems
I run an AMD Ryzen 7 5700G with a Radeon RX 470 graphics card & Windows 10.  I do a lot of video transcoding and am running into varying inconsistencies with AMD Hardware Acceleration and it's really confusing.
The original software I use is ConvertXtoVideo which will utilize acceleration (Open CL?) but when I try other Paid and Open-Source software such as Wondershare Uniconverter, Digiarty's WinxvideoAI or VideoProc or Shutter (open source based on ffmpeg I think) and although they state that they will utilize acceleration in the setup when I attempt to use it in a conversion, it only hits on the CPU and doesn't touch the GPU.  However, I can use Aiseesoft Video Converter with acceleration & it works just fine there.
I'm not very hardware literate so maybe I'm not using the correct terminology or have a lack of understanding in what I'm expecting so I'm turning to the experts here for some input.
Any constructive help would be MOST appreciated!
Thank You!

Hardware acceleration comparability typically is very specific depending on the implementation. These software packages typically outline what hardware they do and don’t support

Do these programs support AMD's acceleration or only NVIDIA?

I've checked most of them and yes, they do support AMD acceleration and some even show the graphics cards they support which include mine.  However, when I go to use it in the program, it only "taps" the CPU and not the GPU.
